# Do not display the product category name on the details page in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

when I want to display the category name of the desired product in the details page, it returns a none value if the brand name of the desired product returns correctly.

```
# model

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='cat_product')
    brand = models.ForeignKey('Brand', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# view

def product_detail(request,id)
    products = product.objects.get(id=id)
    context = {'products': products}
    return render(request, 'home/detail.html', context)

#template

<p>category : {{products.category}}</p>
<br>
<p>category : {{products.brand}}</p>
```

Comment: `products.category` can contain zero, one or *more* `Category`s, so using `{{products.category}}` does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

`products.category` can contain zero, one or *more* `Category`s, so using `{{ products.category }}` does not make much sense. You should enumerate over it, and render the individual categories:

```
<p>category :
  {% for category in products.category.all %}{{ category }}{% endfor %}
</p>
```

---

> **Note**: Since a `ManyToManyField` refers to a *collection* of elements,
> `ManyToManyField`s are normally given a *plural* name. You thus might want
> to consider renaming `category` to `categories`.

Comment: tnx for response